# Add question title to comment links for links to other SE questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, hyperlinks

Often, we put things in comments like "related: judaism.se.com/question/1244" (e.g., [Garments that unintentionally require tzitzit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/garments-that-unintentionally-require-tzitzit#comment10691_5269)).

In a "post" (question or answer) these get rendered as the title of a question (e.g.,  [Garments that unintentionally require tzitzit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5269)).  In a comment, however, it's simply `related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/`.

Is there any way to do give the reader a way to understand the link in the comment without clicking?  For example:

- Automatically change the text in comments just like in questions.
- Automatically give a title attrib to the comment's link

Comment: Note that the URL `http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/garments-that-unintentionally-require-tzitzit` includes a modified version of the title.

Comment: @msh210 .... but notice the link in http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/garments-that-unintentionally-require-tzitzit#comment10691_5269 which does not.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm just saying that this longer URL is one solution: people can (and perhaps should) use it whenever feasible.

Comment: @msh210 My understanding of human nature is that we're only about 80% reliable on a good day.  Machines are generally more reliable.

Comment: @msh210 Also, since we're all obviously here for the badges and nothing else, we all post the links that include our account numbers so we can get the publicist badge :)

Comment: @Daniel, in-network links of that form don't count for badges

Comment: @IsaacMoses Dang. No wonder I haven't gotten there yet :)

Comment: @Daniel, yeah, the feature is nicely designed to recognize you when you, you know, *publicize* the site. :)

Comment: @msh210 clarified to remove title of q in link

Comment: It would be nice, but it's unfortunately just a little too expensive even for the convenience.

Comment: @TimPost thanks and that's fair.  Btw, regarding the dubious claim your profile, I have received a 418 when I curled `BREW  coffee://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2445/tim-post`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been declined on Meta.StackOverflow: [Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments)

However, @TimStone has been kind enough to [write a userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2378/se-comment-link-helper) that accomplishes this, and I've been using it for a while. It only replaces them on submission though, so this is a userscript for the writer, and not the reader.

Comment: I actually think a combination of [these two](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1702/1498) may be ideal.  A userscript that looks in the "related" questions and inserts a title or updates the content for each linked reference

Comment: I'm up for it, are you? :D

Answer (score 1):

You can look in the sidebar, in the "related" section. There the title of the question is displayed.

Comment: But there's no way to know whence in the question/answers/comments those sidebar "related" notes are linked.